# TestNG equivalent of assertEmpty?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

When I want to test whether a returned collection is empty, I found no elegant solution.

```
assertTrue(service.getSomeEntries(params).isEmpty())
```

This approach works, the downside being that it loses any information of the data.

```
assertEquals(new LinkedHashSet<>(service.getSth()), Collections.emptySet())
```

This approach kinda works, it doesn't even change the order. But there is some boilerplate. If this assertion fails, it only shows that the size differs. Better than nothing, but could be better.

Is there any elegant solution to this problem? I don't have any requirements defined, I just want something that fulfills at least one of the following points:

- The code is more ellegant with less boilerplate.
- It provides more information on what lies inside the collection when it's not empty. (This can be obviously achieved by saving the collection outside the assertion and putting it to the text explanation of what went wrong, but is there a way to do it with just an assertion?)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this question since I was downvoted? Or was it just someone's vendetta to my criticism? Having two questions downvoted the very same minute almost looks like the latter.

Answer (score 1):

TestNG does not support such assertions directly. You should either write your own custom assertions, or use [AssertJ library](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) with many build-in assertions.

1. Own custom assertions:

   ```
   asertThat(service).hasZeroEntries()
                     .hasEmptySth();
   ```
2. Build-in AssertJ assertions

   ```
   assertThat(service.getSth()).containsExactly(...)        // 1.)
                               .doesNotContainDuplicates(); // 2.)
   ```

   Where

   1. Will test whether your collection contains only the specified elements in the defined order. If you will defined the elements without duplicates, you have exactly the behaviour you want.
   2. Checks for duplicates. In this case does not matter, but using different assertions can be valuable in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I am rather unsure if I can really use it in the project I am working on (probably not), but it is always nice to learn new things and alternatives. It doesn't answer my question, but I consider this answer useful.

Comment: As I said in the first sentence, there is no alternative in TestNG directly.

Comment: Well, I just want to know a good workaround with TestNG. If I expect the collection to be empty, I am quite curious what is inside if assertion fails.